# Are the Comments and Keywords header fields in IMF (RFC 5322) actually used?

Tags: email, email-client, headers

Internet Message Format (IMF) is specified by RFC 5322.  It defines a variety of header fields, such as `To`, `From`, and `Subject`.

It also defines the `Comments` header field and the `Keywords` header field.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.5

Does anything actually use these two header fields today, or are they totally superfulous? In other words, are mail clients in modern use expected to make use of these?

Comment: I'm not sure what [actual problem](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask) you are facing?

Comment: Pretty simple:  Comments and Keywords are header available to email clients and servers.  As far as I can tell, none of my clients use them.  I am wondering if any clients or servers actually use them.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is considered "not constructive". I'm very curious to know the answer, and answers would certainly be supported by facts and references.

Comment: Closers can be trigger happy.  It happens.

Comment: Made edit to more literally meet SO requirements.

Comment: I don't know any client that does support them. But I think it would be usefull to enable search by keywords. Instead of indexing the whole text of the message. A good practice well explained in "Everything Is Miscellaneous:" by David Weinberger.